# Java webapp memory leak when using ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-leaks

My Tomcat 7 is reporting that there may be a memory leak in my webapp

```
SEVERE: The web application [/mywebapp] appears to have started a 
thread named [pool-1-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is 
very likely to create a  memory leak.
```

I have a long running task in my webapp that gets initialized when the webapp is started.

```
public class MyContextListener implements ServletContextListener{
Scheduler scheduler = null;

public MyContextListener(){
    scheduler = new Scheduler();
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    scheduler.stop();
}

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    scheduler.start();
}

}
```

.. and my Scheduler.java

```
public class Scheduler {
private final ScheduledExecutorService fScheduler;

public Scheduler() {
    fScheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
}


public void start(){
    fScheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Perform some task
        }
    }, 1, 240, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}

public void stop(){
    fScheduler.shutdownNow();
}
```

}

Even though I calling `scheduler.stop();` when shutting down the server, its still reporting there could be a memory leak.

This app is deployed on jelastic.com and I find that once it is started, it runs well for around two days and then the tasks don't seem to  be running. There is no exceptions or errors in the logs too.

Am I doing anything wrong here ? Is there really a potential memory leak ?

Answer (score 6):

Calling `fScheduler.shutdownNow();` is not enough:

> There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks.

From [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow%28%29).

Instead you must explicitly wait for the tasks that are currently running:

```
fScheduler.shutdownNow();
fScheduler.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: hmm.. I thought it may be in rare cases. My task runs every 240 mins and shouldn't take more than a few mins to complete. If at 300th min I try to shutdown, when my task isn't running, shouldn't it be able to shutdown properly ? Your answer is most probably right but I am just curious :)

Comment: @Krishnaraj Are you sure that your task is terminating as quickly as you think it should?  You may want to log when your task starts / stops to verify it is not blocking.

Comment: @increment1 Yes, my tasks do complete in not more than 5 mins.

Comment: I ended up recording the ScheduledFuture<?> object returned by the schedule method, and when I shut down I explicitly cancel all those before shutting down the scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should not call the shutdown from the Listener but from the Servlet directly.

`contextDestroyed()` of the listener is too late for the executor service. As stated in the javadoc *All servlets and filters will have been destroyed* **before** *any ServletContextListeners are notified of context destruction.*

whereas overriding the servlet `destroy()` should be OK as according to the javadoc *This method gives the servlet an opportunity to clean up any resources that are being held (for example, memory, file handles,* **threads**...

```
@Override
public void destroy(  ) {


     fScheduler.shutdownNow();
     fScheduler.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

     super.destroy(  );
}
```

Comment: Using Servlet.destroy() is a very bad idea. The container is free to unload a Servlet from memory (calling destroy() in the process) whenever it likes.

Comment: @MarkThomas Also ex the `Servlet` Javadoc *After the servlet container calls this method, it will not call the service method again on this servlet.*. In other words, the servlet will never be used again. I cannot see what your problem is. If you tie a resource to this servlet (Thread, file handles,...) when `destroy()` is called, the servlet is just that, definitively destroyed, and any tied resource should be destroyed too.

Comment: You need to read the Servlet spec, particularly the sesion on servlet lifecycle. The init() method gets called once when the instance is created (one instance is created to handle all requests). The service() method gets called once per request. The same instance can handle multiple concurrent requests. The destroy() method gets called when the instance is unloaded which can be at any point in time (if another request is received for the servlet after the instance has been destroyed new instance will be created). This all ignores the depreacted single threaded model.

Comment: @MarkThomas I read it and that is my point. If you tie a resource in the init() method, you need to destroy it in the destroy() method because if your servlet is disposed and a new instance is created, the init() method of the new instance will be called, tieing your resource again again.